# Having a problem with sending inputs of type radio to mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a form with multiple inputs of type radio, with the same names but different values. All the inputs are placed in the table. I want user to select one answer in each row and submit, so answers sent to db. But I getting an error:

```
Error: INSERT INTO `teachers_ans` (mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4, mark5, mark6, mark7, mark8, 
mark9, mark10, mark11, 2mark, 3mark, 4mark1, 4mark2, 4mark3, 4mark4, 4mark5, 4mark6, 4mark7, 
4mark8, 4mark9, 5mark1, 5mark2, 5mark3, 5mark4, 5mark5, 5mark6, 5mark7, 5mark8, 5mark9, 
5mark10, 5mark11, 6mark) VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 
'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 
'1', '1', '1', 'SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS') Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

And here is the HTML and PHP code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
        // get all inputs values
        @$A1_1 = $_POST['mark1'];
        @$A1_2 = $_POST['mark2'];
        @$A1_3 = $_POST['mark3'];
        @$A1_4 = $_POST['mark4'];
        @$A1_5 = $_POST['mark5'];
        @$A1_6 = $_POST['mark6'];
        @$A1_7 = $_POST['mark7'];
        @$A1_8 = $_POST['mark8'];
        @$A1_9 = $_POST['mark9'];
        @$A1_10 = $_POST['mark10'];
        @$A1_11 = $_POST['mark11'];
        @$A2 = $_POST['2mark'];
        @$A3 = $_POST['3mark'];
        @$A4_1 = $_POST['4mark1'];
        @$A4_2 = $_POST['4mark2'];
        @$A4_3 = $_POST['4mark3'];
        @$A4_4 = $_POST['4mark4'];
        @$A4_5 = $_POST['4mark5'];
        @$A4_6 = $_POST['4mark6'];
        @$A4_7 = $_POST['4mark7'];
        @$A4_8 = $_POST['4mark8'];
        @$A4_9 = $_POST['4mark9'];
        @$A5_1 = $_POST['5mark1'];
        @$A5_2 = $_POST['5mark2'];
        @$A5_3 = $_POST['5mark3'];
        @$A5_4 = $_POST['5mark4'];
        @$A5_5 = $_POST['5mark5'];
        @$A5_6 = $_POST['5mark6'];
        @$A5_7 = $_POST['5mark7'];
        @$A5_8 = $_POST['5mark8'];
        @$A5_9 = $_POST['5mark9'];
        @$A5_10 = $_POST['5mark10'];
        @$A5_11 = $_POST['5mark11'];
        @$A6 = $_POST['6mark'];
        //init db params
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "teachers";

        print_r($_POST);

       // create connection to the db
       $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      // check connection errors, if found, display it
      if (!$conn) { echo "ERROR: " . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn); }

      $sql_send_query = "INSERT INTO `teachers_ans` (mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4, mark5, 
                                                    mark6, mark7,
                                              mark8, mark9, mark10, mark11, 2mark, 3mark, 
                                              4mark1, 4mark2, 4mark3, 4mark4, 4mark5,  
                                                                 4mark6,
                                              4mark7, 4mark8, 4mark9, 5mark1, 5mark2, 
                                                    5mark3,
                                              5mark4, 5mark5, 5mark6, 5mark7, 5mark8, 
                                                5mark9,
                                              5mark10, 5mark11, 6mark)
                   VALUES ('$A1_1', '$A1_2', '$A1_3', '$A1_4', '$A1_5', '$A1_6',
                           '$A1_7', '$A1_8', '$A1_9', '$A1_10', '$A1_11', 
                           '$A2', '$A3', '$A4_1', '$A4_2', '$A4_3', '$A4_4', '$A4_5',
                           '$A4_6', '$A4_7', '$A4_8', '$A4_9', '$A5_1', '$A5_2', '$A5_3'
                           '$A5_4', '$A5_5', '$A5_6', '$A5_7', '$A5_8', '$A5_9', '$A5_10',
                           '$A5_11', '$A6')";

    if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql_send_query))
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql_send_query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Question 1</td>
            <td><input type="radio" id="mark" name="mark1" value="1"><span>1</span></td>
            <td><input type="radio" id="mark" name="mark1" value="2"><span>2</span></td>
            <td><input type="radio" id="mark" name="mark1" value="3"><span>3</span></td>
            <td><input type="radio" id="mark" name="mark1" value="4"><span>4</span></td>
            <td><input type="radio" id="mark" name="mark1" value="5"><span>5</span></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I've also tried to write variables without @, but it didn't help.
What should I do here? Please, help :)

Comment: Wow, you really did this the most difficult way possible. Your error indicates you aren't passing the same number of variables as there are columns in your insert.

Comment: your should really research into PHP arrays

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should look into prepared statements and parameterized queries.

Comment: A hint is that HTML will only send the value that is selected for each `name`. Another hint is array notation, instead of using the name `mark1` try `mark[1]`, then you can access the selected value with `$_POST['mark'][1]` which means you can loop through them easily.

Comment: This database layout seems as if it could be better.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so this is a fun little project to explore and expand on.

As mentioned by myself and [**GrumpyCrouton**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64449469/having-a-problem-with-sending-inputs-of-type-radio-to-mysql-database#comment113962914_64449469) in comments, you should be looking at [**PHP arrays**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) to hold your data in a form of *list*.

You should be also looking at completely redesigning how your database is structured, but I guess this is a school project so you'll get to that at some point, I hope.

Arrays make it much easier to iterate over the list and makes for almost no repetition in your code.

## To answer your actual question:

You asked

> Having a problem with sending inputs of type radio to mysql database

So, radio button inputs are set out as:

```css
label {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<label><input type='radio' name='something' value='1'>Click me One</label>
<label><input type='radio' name='something' value='2'>Click me Two</label>
```

So when this form is submitted, the value  `$_POST['something']` will either be empty (nothing clicked so nothing is sent to the PHP), or value `1` or `2`.

---

## NOTE:

Prepared statements are the best way of using MySQL / PHP interfacing but for the sake of ease I will [not dig into that here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo), instead focusing on the underlying basics of how array's can help you

So; let's try it out.

## First

- It looks like your HTML input names are exactly equal to your MySQL column names. Therefore you can use these key values when constructing your SQL.
- You will have a set of key `->` value pairs, where the "key" is the name of the input field and the SQL column and the value is what value this column has.

## Second

Our process will be to cycle through the data given by the form to the PHP and to sort it into an array, before then manipulating that array into an SQL execution string, ready to be run by the MySQL handler.

The advantage of this is that by its nature this will not try to insert empty values.

## Less talk, more code

```
// You may have to remove unwanted POST values from the POST array before this line
// You can also use this foreach loop to add custom functions/tweaks to each given value

foreach($_POST as $key=>$row){
     $insert[$key] = $row;
}
unset($key,$row);
```

Now we have an array of elements (actually a duplicate of the POSTED data) we can have some fun with it.

```
$insert = array_filter($insert); // remove empty values (optional)
// https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php
$column = $data = []; // set two empty arrays

foreach($insert as $key=>$value){
   $column[] = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i','', $key); // Security measure: PCRE Regex removes all non alphanumeric characters. Tweak for your own needs.
   $data[] = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i','',$value); // Security measure: PCRE Regex removes all non alphanumeric characters. Tweak for your own needs. 
}

// https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode
$columns = implode(",", $column);
$datas = implode("','", $data); 
// note the quote marks because you appear to be inserting into string columns.
```

And now we insert these data and column values into the SQL instruction:

```
// note the outer single quote marks on the $datas string insert. 
$sql_send_query = "INSERT INTO `teachers_ans` (".$columns.") VALUES ('".$datas."')";

if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql_send_query))
{
    echo "Error: " . $sql_send_query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

> ## I UNDERLINE THIS IS NOT CODE FOR PRODUCTION; THIS IS ONLY TO SHOW HOW ARRAYS CAN CUT REPETITION AND DE-JA-VU LOOPS.

---

## Production version

First, qualifier that each of your radio button answers are in their own array; such as:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Question 1</td>
            <td><input type="radio" id="mark" name="answer[mark1]" value="1"><span>1</span></td>
            <td><input type="radio" id="mark" name="answer[mark1]" value="2"><span>2</span></td>
            <td><input type="radio" id="mark" name="answer[mark1]" value="3"><span>3</span></td>
            <td><input type="radio" id="mark" name="answer[mark1]" value="4"><span>4</span></td>
            <td><input type="radio" id="mark" name="answer[mark1]" value="5"><span>5</span></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

So that all your `mark`s will be in the $_POST array `answers` (`$_POST['answers']`)

Then we need to set up PDO :

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'something';
$user = 'someone';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4'; //best one to use. 

$dsn = "mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$db.";charset=".$charset;
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $ex) {
     throw new \PDOException($ex->getMessage(), (int)$ex->getCode());
}
```

Now you have a working PDO object `$pdo`.

```
foreach($_POST['answers'] as $key=>$row){
     $key = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i','', $key); // Security measure
     $insert[$key] = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/i','', $row); //numeric values only 
}
unset($key,$row);

$columns = implode(",", array_keys($insert));
$references = ":".implode(", :", array_keys($insert)); //PDO SQL references.

$sql_send_query = "INSERT INTO `teachers_ans` (".$columns.") VALUES (".$references.")";

$pdo->prepare($sql_send_query)->execute($insert);

print "data inserted; insert ID is ".$pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: OK, thanks, I did all of that like you recommended, but now it gives another error: undefined index 'answers'  ans SQL syntax error:   Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':)' at line 1 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Questioning/form2.php:72 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Questioning/form2.php(72): PDO->prepare('INSERT INTO `te...') #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Questioning/form2.php on line 72

Comment: @MrMe that sounds like a typo. paste in to a comment exactly what the SQL generated is?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':)' at line 1 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Questioning/form2.php:72 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Questioning/form2.php(72): PDO->prepare('INSERT INTO `te...') #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Questioning/form2.php on line 72

Comment: and my query is                                                                                     
$sql_send_query = "INSERT INTO `teachers_ans` (".$columns.") VALUES (".$references.")";

Comment: and in for loop  it gives undefined index error                                                                                                                   foreach($_POST['answers'] as $key=>$row)
{
     $key = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i','', $key); // Security measure
      $insert[$key] = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/i','', $row); //numeric values only 
}
unset($key,$row);

Comment: @MrMe you need to read the answer and adjust your code accordingly. the `$sql_send_query` should be a complete SQL instruction it should not contain literal `$columns` or literal `$references`. You need to build your `<input>` list of radio buttons as described on the answer.